# How quickly will websocket in the dev versions of Firefox and Chrome be moved to the official releases?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, websocket

I realize that this is hard/maybe impossible to estimate - but any estimation, even plus or minus 6 months, would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't comment on Chrome, but Mozilla is releasing Firefox 3.6 now (without web sockets), and it's not a feature likely to be included in minor releases (3.6.x), so the earliest release it is likely to ship in is the next major release (assuming the [implementation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=472529) is finished soon).

When that release might happen is probably not known even among the Mozilla leads, but probably no sooner than 6 months (there wasn't even an alpha released). My guess is 10.2010 ± 4 months.

(Of course, this is pure speculation and you shouldn't use this other than for your personal amusement.)

Comment: BTW, Chrome 5 has them <http://chrome.blogspot.com/2010/05/new-chrome-stable-release-welcome-mac.html>, but will change incompatibly due to changes in the spec <http://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/websocket-protocol-updated.html>